# How to fix docker network timeout?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to start a project that I was used to start every day, in theses last couple days when I try it I got the error saying:

> ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
> If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).

I've tried:

1. pruning docker (docker system prune -a)
2. restarting docker (sudo service docker restart), freezes the terminal.
3. reinstalling docker
4. increasing the timeout (COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=200 docker-compose up -d)
5. deleting the network (docker network rm)

What am I using:

```sh
Ubuntu: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (focal)
Docker version: Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
Docker compose version: docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e
```

What else can I do to fix this compose HTTP timeout?

Comment: please add your container image names and\or Dockerfiles for the applications as well as the docker-compose.yml file if possible. also if you can please add `docker system df -v` + `docker images` + `docker ps -a` output